# Can I explain it right? [Objective-C starter]

Tags: objective-c

I´ve been learning Objective-C for a while now and today I was watching one of the first videos I started learning with. While watching I was asking myself if I could explain it to others myself. Without the help of the video and my cheatsheet.

I would be really happy if someone would read this and see if I place the keywords right because I think I really made a connection there in my head (I will make sure to highlight the keywords I meant)

A **class** is comparable to a Car factory. It can fabricate as many cars as is needed. The cars coming out of the factory can be seen as **instances** because they´re all the same in general. There can be a red car next to a blue car. Looking different they both have the same **properties**.

In code I made my own example for trying things out:

I created the class `Person`. A characteristic of every `Person` is their age. So I created a property age `@property age`. My imaginary person Tom should be an instance of the class `Person`. To get access to my tom-property (person.tom) I first needed to **allocate** him in memory. So by allocating and **initializing** him, I gave him memory space and a pointer so the **compiler** could find him there. Doing it like this `Person *tom = [[Person alloc] init];` I **declared** tom inside the class and tom got bounded to the class `Person`. Finally, I could initialize the value to him by setting his age `tom.age = 21;`

Comment: Not sure this is the right place for you to be asking this. This doesn't really relate to any particular programming issue.

Comment: @Popeye can you recommend me a better place?

Comment: A car is a class, the car is an instance. What is unclear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got almost everything right!

However when you write:

> I gave him memory space and a pointer so the **compiler** could find him there

It is not quite correct, because the **compiler** checks the syntax of the instructions you wrote at the *build time*

So it **is not the compiler** who would find the object **tom** at given address in memory (using `*tom` pointer)

====>

**it is the program/application itself in it's runtime**, who would find object **tom** (by means of Objective-C runtime system) to perform further actions (send messages to it, etc).

Comment: Thank you very much for your correction I got it now! :)

Comment: it wasn't me who downvoted you. I am new to stackoverflow so I can't give you an upvote. Really sorry about that

Comment: its perfectly fine, no need to artificially upvote ;) ! I just wanted to know what's wrong with my post, so I could correct it

Answer (score 0):

Almost right, I think you got the idea, some corrections:

> I created the class Person. A characteristic of every Person is their age. So I created a property age @property age. My imaginary person Tom should be an instance of the class Person.

so far so good

> To get access to my tom-property (person.tom)

tom is not a property. Cars aren't property of the factory.

> I first needed to allocate him in memory. So by allocating and initializing him, I gave him memory space and a pointer so the compiler could find him there. Doing it like this Person *tom = [[Person alloc] init]; I declared tom inside the class and tom got bounded to the class Person.

tom is not declared inside the class. You declared a local variable `tom`. A compiler is a tool to translate source code into machine code (build). The compiler can find `tom` in other parts of your source code but doesn't find tom in memory. At runtime (run), when the machine code is executed, your app and the Objective-C runtime allocate and initialize an instance of `Person` and can find tom in memory.

> Finally, I could initialize the value to him by setting his age tom.age = 21;

The initialization of `tom` is in the `init…` method. If you want to set the age during initialization, you can declare a method `initWithAge:(NSUInteger)age` and set the property age in this method or you can set a default age in `init`. You can set the age later on but this isn't initializing.